# Multiplying an inequality with an argument

Tags: inequality, fractions

I have a question about the following inequality:

$a - \frac{2}{a} + 1 > 0$

This is obviously a polynomial of the second degree.

Is this the simplest way of solving the given equation?

$\frac{a}{a} * (a - \frac{2}{a} + 1 > 0) > 0$

$\frac{a^2 - 2 + a}{a}>0$

$\frac{(a-1)(a+2)}{a}>0$

$a \in (-2,0) \cup (1, +\infty)$

... or is there a faster/mathematically "cleaner" way of doing it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is OK. I would instead multiply through by $a$ and keep track of the inequality reversal when $a < 0$.